# How to open an uml2 .tex?

Tags: uml, tex

I apologize if this this is an extremely amateur question. But before yesterday I had never even heard to tex, latex, mactex, all this stuff.

Basically I have cloned a git repo in which the UML documents appear to be in a .tex file. Following google, this has led me to install MacTex, try to open these files. Click 'typeset' which I presume is how it produces the document, but it gives an error about 'uml2' being invalid syntax.

What program, or what anything, am I supposed to use to open a .tex file which has stuff like this in it:

```
\tikzstyle{uml2} = [
    fill=rupBody,
    draw=rupBorder,
    font={\ttfamily},
]
```

Is this even something your supposed to open in a program and view visually? I suppose this file named uml.tex will show a UML diagram once opened. Or do I have completely the wrong idea? Sorry if this is extremely amateur, like I said I've never heard of this since before yesterday, and google isn't turning up lots of information on this. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: What environment? On Mac use TexShop. Under Windoze there are also some nice out-of-the-box LaTex packages. Ah. See MacTex. So you likely need some extra package to be installed to swallow UMLTex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install pgf from http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf The easiest is to use TexLive. Once you got all packages installed you can typeset the TeX file. I'm using TexShop which is a nice app for the Mac.

Since you indicate you never heard of TeX before: TeX is a program written by Donald Knuth many, many years ago when computers were engined with steam. But it's the best you can find for typesetting. It's mature, crude and more than 99,99% error free. Donald Knuth has a bounty for each error you find in the code and he did not have to pay since many years. What you do is to create those TeX files (there are different macro packages were LaTeX is the most famous) and send them to the TeX processor. That will create the output (now its PDF and formerly it was some DIV (device independent viewer IIRC)).

**Edit** I downloaded tikz-uml from here: http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php and moved the `tikz-uml.sty` to folder where the main .tex source is placed. After including

```
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
```

in the header I was able to compile the source.

Note: there is a global location for `.sty` files but that depends in the app you use. Use Google to find this place. But putting `.sty` near your `.tex` is fine anyway. A `\usepackage` directive first looks in the source folder before looking into the global ones.

Comment: I am using MacTex and I looked in the 'TexLive Utility' and pgf is listed as installed. But it still doesn't typeset my UML.

The error it says is:
./uml2.tex:30: Undefined Control Sequence.
l.30 \tikzstyle {uml2} = [ ?

Comment: Can you post the a link to the source? I'd give it a try

Comment: Its the uml2 for s3auth https://github.com/yegor256/s3auth/blob/master/src/main/latex/uml2.tex

Comment: What is the source folder? The source folder for mactex? I don't see that anywhere.

Comment: No. It's just where your .tex source rests. Just put the file aside. There is also a common place but that depends on the app you use. I have to find that via google any time I need it (very rare).